# Android Studio removes modules falsely identified as not backed by Gradle

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem with Android Studio 0.3.0 and my project folder containing a plain old java library project, two Android library projects, and three Android apps. It's all built with Gradle.

The problem is that the initial import into Android Studio works fine (using Android Studio's `Import Project...`, then choosing my `settings.gradle` file), but when I press the refresh button in the Gradle sidebar, I get the message "The modules below are not backed by Gradle anymore. Check those to be removed from the ide project too:", and then it lists ALL my modules for removal. Everything builds fine from the terminal.

Output of `gradle projects` is (with edited names):

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'root'
+--- Project ':android-lib1'
+--- Project ':android-app1'
+--- Project ':android-app2'
+--- Project ':android-app3'
+--- Project ':android-lib2'
\--- Project ':java-lib'
```

In the root folder, I have `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':java-lib'
include ':android-lib1'
include ':android-lib2'
include ':android-app1'
include ':android-app2'
include ':android-app3'
```

My `build.gradle` in the root folder:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        ivy {
            name 'repo'
            artifactPattern 'http://repo.example.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]'
            credentials {
                username 'example'
                password 'example'
            }
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

`build.gradle` for java-lib:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

group 'example'
version '0.1.0'
status 'release'

sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
targetCompatibility = '1.6'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        add project.repositories.repo
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` for the two Android libs (they are the same apart from dependencies and version numbers:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile project(':java-lib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1.0'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

And finally, `build.gradle` for the Android apps (again, almost identical):

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':android-lib1')
    compile project(':android-lib2')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1.0'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

if (project.hasProperty('storeFile')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(storeFile)
}
if (project.hasProperty('storePassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePassword
}
if (project.hasProperty('keyAlias')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
}
if (project.hasProperty('keyPassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPassword
}
```

Perhaps it's a bug in Android Studio 0.3.0? I didn't experience it in earlier versions, but I want to make sure it's not just something in my build files.

Thanks a bunch for reading!

Comment: I've now reported this as a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61453 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug which has now been fixed (working for me since Android Studio 0.3.5): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61453

Answer (score 0):

Also got this or very similar error (don't know if I did refresh)  I see you posted bug at code.google.com and agree it must be their bug.  My work around fix was just to cancel out of "not backed by Gradle" message and then I ran gradle build from command line. Then everything worked.

Comment: They've since fixed the bug. Thanks for your suggestion, though!